# ¿El programa no itera ni calcula los resultados esperados?

Tags: c++, archivo, csv

Estoy intentando crear una funcion que al mirar una lista de valores de un archivo .csv en el cual hay 3 datos por linea, id, gender y age. Tras la ejecuccion se cuentan cuantos M y F habia pero al ejecutar el codigo al final obtengo que el la iteracion del while solo se ejecuta una vez y que solo tengo una M ya que solo se ha ejecutado el codigo una vez. Cuando he forzado a que iterase un numero de veces me dice que solo hay M's lo que me lleva a pensar a que seguramente este leyendo los datos de forma erronea. El codigo que he escrito es:

```
else{
    ifstream f;
    f.open (direccion1);
    if (f.is_open()){
    string female = "F";
    string male = "M";
    int females = 0;
    int males = 0;
    string idU;
    string gender;
    string age;
        while (getline (f, idU, ',')){                      
            getline (f, gender, ',');
            getline (f, age, '\n');

            if (gender == female){
                females++;
            }
            else if (gender == male){
                males++;
            }
        }

    cout << "\nUsos de Bizi por hombres: " << males;
    cout << "\nUsos de Bizi por mujeres: " << females;
    f.close();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puse para probar un contador de iteraciones dentro del while y en efecto solo se ejecuto una vez y por mucho que miro no consigo ver el error. Tambien para mas informacion aqui dejo el diseño del fichero .csv

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras estar probando con varias cosas y editar la condicion del bucle a `getline (f, idU, ',')` si que recorre el fichero correctamente pero no guarda los valores especificos tras cada comprobacion de gender

Comment: El último `getline( )` debería ser `getline (f, age );`. Te sobra el último argumento.

Comment: Ya recorre el archivo correctamente, pero ¿Qué resultados te muestra ahora o por qué dices que no guarda los valores específicos de gender?